# React does not recognize the `justifyContent` prop on a DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
root:{
    padding: 0,
    textAlign: 'left',
    flexDirection: '100vh',
},
}));
    

return (
    <Container>
    <div className={classes.root}>
    <Grid container spacing={2} className={classes.Grid} justifyContent="center">
        <Grid item xs={12}>
            <RadioGroup row  aria-label="type" name="name"  className={classes.weightradio} defaultValue={"1"} value={weightRadio} onChange={handleWeightRadio}> 
                <FormControlLabel value="1"  control={<Radio />} label="1kg" />
                <FormControlLabel value="2"  control={<Radio />} label="2kg" />
                <FormControlLabel value="others"  control={<Radio />} label=">3kg" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </Grid>
        .....
   </Gid>
```

log show me---

> index.js:1 Warning: React does not recognize the `justifyContent` prop
> on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as
> a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `justifycontent` instead. If
> you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the
> DOM element.

I have checked the doc of MUI 4.0, `justifyContent` is supported, where is the problem.

Comment: Can you please provide working example of it in codesandbox

Comment: Have you tried to use `justify` prop instead? It seems that at some point on [v4.x.x](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.x/packages/material-ui/src/Grid/Grid.js#L307-L329) it got renamed to `justifyContent` so maybe you are using an older version.

Comment: @fgkolf thanks for your help , you are right , it is justify .

Answer (score 2):

Ok I got the answer.

justify instead of justifyContent , and should not set to Grid root , correct code as below ,

```
        <Grid container spacing={2} className={classes.Grid}>
        <Grid item xs={12} container justify="center">   //changed here 
            <RadioGroup row  aria-label="type" name="name"  className={classes.weightradio} defaultValue={"1"} value={weightRadio} onChange={handleWeightRadio}> 
                <FormControlLabel value="1"  control={<Radio />} label="1kg" />
                <FormControlLabel value="2"  control={<Radio />} label="2kg" />
                <FormControlLabel value="others"  control={<Radio />} label=">3kg" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference in versions. Not all 4.* versions support justifyContent Probably versions earlier than 4.12 operate only justify:
https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/21845

For 4.11.4 this is definitely the case